# google charts remove event listener

Tags: events, google-visualization, listener

I haven't seen much documentation and cant seem to get my code to work. the code snippet is below. I'm trying to remove the on mouse over listener but have had no success. Google charts docs has the method as such - google.visualization.events.remove Listener(listener_handler).

I'm uncertain what the listener_handler actually pertains to. Im trying to remove the on mouse over listener once the chart has been clicked.

```js
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover',  chartMouseOver);
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseout', chartMouseOut);

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
    google.visualization.events.removeListener(chartMouseOver);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to store the returned event object in a variable, and pass that to `removeListener` :

```js
var event = google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function() {
    alert('onmouseover');
    google.visualization.events.removeListener(event); //the event object as param
});
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/cmDT2/**

Comment: Why is this not in google's docs?!

Comment: @DoubleA, Dont know, google dev docs have always been confusing and almost useless. I am really surprised that not even today, 7 years after, this really simple and very common pattern is not documented officially. g.v.e.add/remove~Listener are basically just wrappers around JS' addEventListener, removeEventListener, but for some reason google dont want that eureka-moment to happen  :(